# xml:space in resource file of c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I have a windows form application in that i have `resource file(.resx)`here i write all my error messages like below

```
 <data name="Link_Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The Link Name must be not blank and not greater than 255 symbols.</value>
  </data>
```

Here i understood name is the name of the resource which needs to be accessed and the value is the value of the resource 
But i did not get what is `xml:space="preserve"` ? 
i have one more option there `default`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xml:space="preserve" makes that whitespaces at the begin of the tag is not removed. (And also if you place more than one whitespace together)

example:

```
<data name="Link_Name" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>      The Link Name must be not blank and not greater than 255 symbols.</value>
</data>
```

Now the value will be:

```
"      The Link Name must be not blank and not greater than 255 symbols."
```

If xml:space is not set:

```
<data name="Link_Name">
   <value>      The Link Name must be not blank and not greater than 255 symbols.</value>
</data>
```

The value will be:

```
"The Link Name must be not blank and not greater than 255 symbols."
```

So xml:space="preserve" preserves the whtespaces at begin of the tag.

Comment: Default is equivalent to not giving anything ?